# Vue 3 Components Not Loading

Tags: vue.js

I've spent the last 5 hours trying to figure out what's not working with my setup.

What I basically want to do is have a "wrapper" app that loads my common codebase (which is a Vue component).

App.js

```js
import { createApp } from "vue";
import AppWrapper from "@src/js/AppWrapper.vue";

import Router from "@common/libraries/Router.js";

const vm = createApp(AppWrapper);
vm.use(Router);
vm.mount("#app");
```

AppWrapper.vue

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <app></app>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import App from "@common/App.vue";

export default {
  created() {},
  components: {
    App,
  },
};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped></style>
```

App.vue

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Ok</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  created() {},
};
</script>
```

Somehow, the app tag isn't replaced and my component is not loading in the page.

Here's the webpack file:

```js
const Webpack = require("webpack");
const path = require("path");
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require("vue-loader");
const LiveReloadPlugin = require("webpack-livereload-plugin");

module.exports = (env) => {
  return {
    entry: {
      app: ["./app/src/common/App.js"],
    },
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, "public/"),
      filename: "js/[name].js",
      sourceMapFilename: "js/[name].js.map",
    },
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        "@src": path.resolve(__dirname, "app/src/"),
        "@common": path.resolve(__dirname, "app/src/common/"),
      },
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.vue$/,
          use: ["vue-loader"],
        },
      ],
    },
    watchOptions: {
      aggregateTimeout: 300,
      poll: 500,
      ignored: /node_modules/,
    },
    plugins: [new VueLoaderPlugin(), new LiveReloadPlugin()],
  };
};
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I figured it out. Vue was loaded twice, once in my app package.json and once in the common sources. Removing it from one location worked!